# Schedule Interactive UILocalNotification - Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to schedule an interactive `UILocalNotifaction`.

My attempt has been to use the following code, which I grabbed from this [tutorial](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8):

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

However, this code doesn't seem to actually schedule the notification anywhere. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you implement `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` method in your app delegate?

Comment: @soulshined i mean no but that shouldn't have any effect on the scheduling of the notification...

Comment: You still have to schedule a local notification like any other notification. Here your just registering for that type of notification which is a category.

Comment: @soulshined right and my question is how to do that. If you can answer that it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo,

Scheduling a local notification is relatively easy. Piggy backing off the tutorial you referenced I kind of switched it up so it can make more sense, you can deter or alter the code as need be, but this will give you a better starting point than the tutorial did. Please know it's not mandatory to put this in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you can schedule a `UILocalNotification` anywhere app-wide. See the references below for complete properties of each method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Here we are just going to create the actions for the category. 
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction = [self createAction];
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *laterAction = [self createLaterAction];
laterAction.title = @"Not Now";

//Creating the category and assigning the actions:
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *acceptCategory = [self createCategory:@[acceptAction, laterAction]];

//Register the categories 
[self registerCategorySettings:acceptCategory];

//For testing purposes we will just fire a local notification on load. This is just for reference, but you don't have to call it in applicationDidFinishLaunching
[self fireLocalNotification];

return YES;
}

//Create a category
- (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *)createCategory:(NSArray *)actions {
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *acceptCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
acceptCategory.identifier = @"ACCEPT_CATEGORY";

[acceptCategory setActions:actions forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

return acceptCategory;
}

//Register your settings for that category 
- (void)registerCategorySettings:(UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *)category {
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:category, nil];
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}

//Create Actions Methods
- (UIMutableUserNotificationAction *)createAction {

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
acceptAction.identifier = @"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER";
acceptAction.title = @"Accept";

acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
acceptAction.destructive = NO;

// If YES requires passcode
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

return acceptAction;
}

- (UIMutableUserNotificationAction *)createLaterAction {

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *laterAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
laterAction.identifier = @"LATER_IDENTIFIER";
laterAction.title = @"Not Now";

laterAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
laterAction.destructive = NO;
laterAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

return laterAction;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {

UIUserNotificationType allowedTypes = [notificationSettings types];
NSLog(@"Registered for notification types: %u", allowedTypes);
}

//Fire a local Notification: For testing purposes we are just going to fire this immediately after launch. But this will give you a general idea of how to create a UILocalNotification app-wide:
- (void)fireLocalNotification {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = @"We are just testing -";
notification.category = @"ACCEPT_CATEGORY";

notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:15 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

And your outcome will be as anticipated:
[image: pic1]

Don't forget to call the completion handlers for the actions that were selected. 
`application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:`

Please review the documentation and references below for further customization. Again, i'm not saying this is the right way and it's definetly not the only, it's just a great starting point for you to understand how they work. There are lots of customizable properties for actions and `UILocalNotifications`

---

**REFERENCES**

- UILocalNotification & Properties : [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html)
- iOS8 Notification Actions & Properties : [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationAction_class/index.html)

Comment: What if I want to Trigger 10 notification in a for loop? Each notification with different category and different action buttons

Comment: I am following same steps and triggering 10 to 15 notifications at a time in a for loop and my 1st notification shows up action buttons and second one onwards it fails to catch up the buttons

Comment: @iOSdev that seems to be fitting for a different question. It's SO etiquette to not answer another question within a different question, creates clutter and people looking for the same answer won't find it because it's in an unrelated topic like this one. I would suggest starting a new question topic if its not related to this one