# Action Buttons won't show in Notification

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add iOS8 Action Buttons to my already working notifications. But they won't show up. It's just a normal notification without buttons.

```
//Action
UIMutableUserNotificationAction* loginAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
loginAction.identifier = @"loginAction"; //ID string to be passed back to your app when you handle the action
loginAction.title = @"login";
loginAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
loginAction.destructive = NO;
loginAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

//Category
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory* loginCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
loginCategory.identifier = @"loginCategory"; //ID to include in your push payload
[loginCategory setActions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:loginAction, nil] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

//Register Settings and Notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:[NSSet setWithObject:loginCategory]]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Using this code will have the same effect as setting the categories parameter to nil.

The payload looks like this:

```
'{"aps":{"alert":{"body":"text"},"category":"loginCategory"}}'
```

I just added the category key to the payload.

What am i missing?

Comment: See my answer here for a walk through : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28059691/2353523

Comment: You have to add the category key into the aps dictionary and not after it or in the alert dictionary. Also moving to the side won't show the button. I have to move the finger down.

Comment: Moving to side does show the buttons. Look at the os mail notification

Comment: oh yeah, in the lockscreen. But in the top notification it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example, in Objective-C, of how to register a notification that has 2 actions.

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] 
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

To send this type of notification simply add the category to the payload.

```
"aps" : { 
    "alert"    : "Pull down to interact.",
    "category" : "ACTIONABLE"
}
```

These methods will get called, in the background, when the user selects an action from your push notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {

        NSLog(@"You chose action 1.");
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {   

        NSLog(@"You chose action 2.");
    }    
    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...cheers !!!